# How to hook WndProc in WINUI

Tags: c#, subclassing, wndproc, winui

Over the years, I've hooked the WndProc in everything from VB3 to C# in WinForms with no issue, but WINUI-3 and C# is giving me problems.

My DLL Imports are:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Sets window data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd">The handle of the window to set.</param>
        /// <param name="nIndex">The index of the item to set.</param>
        /// <param name="dwNewLong">The new value.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll",
            EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtr",
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr64(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);

        // Defines our window WndProcDelegate.
        private delegate IntPtr WndProcDelegate(IntPtr hwnd, uint message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        // This handles calling the underlying base WndProc.
        [DllImport("user32.dll", 
            CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
            CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr CallWindowProc(WndProcDelegate lpPrevWndFunc, IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

The actual subclass/unsubclass etc, look like this:

```
 public IntPtr GetHwnd()
        {
            IntPtr handle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this.m_MainWindow);
            return handle;
        }

// Subclass the window.
        public void Subclass(object window)
        {
            if (this.m_isSubclassed)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.m_MainWindow = window;
            this.m_NewWndProcDelegate = new WndProcDelegate(this.ReplacementWndProc);
            IntPtr hWnd = this.GetHwnd();
            HandleRef handleRef = new(this, hWnd);
            IntPtr newDelegatePtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(this.m_NewWndProcDelegate);
            IntPtr oldDelegatePtr = SetWindowLongPtr64(handleRef, GWLP_WNDPROC, newDelegatePtr);
            this.m_OldWndProcDelegate = (WndProcDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
                oldDelegatePtr,
                typeof(WndProcDelegate));
            this.m_isSubclassed = true;
        }

// Unsubclass the window.
        public void Unsubclass()
        {
            if (!this.m_isSubclassed)
            {
                return;
            }
            IntPtr hWnd = this.GetHwnd();
            SetWindowLongPtr64(new HandleRef(this, hWnd), GWLP_WNDPROC, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(this.m_OldWndProcDelegate));
            this.m_isSubclassed = false;
        }

        public bool IsSubclassed()
        {
            return this.m_isSubclassed;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// This is the replacement WndProc.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hwnd"></param>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        /// <param name="wParam"></param>
        /// <param name="lParam"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private IntPtr ReplacementWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, uint message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            // Our custom Windows messages code...
            /*if (message == WM_COPYDATA)
            {
                CopyDataStruct copyStruct = (CopyDataStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(CopyDataStruct));
                string messageText = Utf8PtrToString(copyStruct.lpData);
                int cbData = copyStruct.cbData;
                // Do something with the messageText and cbData.
            }*/

            // Finally, call the original WndProc.
            return CallWindowProc(this.m_OldWndProcDelegate, hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
```

The issue I have is a nebulous SystemEngineException (-2146233082) error, with all null information.

So, something has clearly gone wrong in my implementation.  Is there a tried/tested way to do this with WINUI?

For anyone wondering why I'm trying to do this, I need to handle a WM_COPYDATA message.

Many thanks in advance,

Jason

Comment: `SetLongWindowPtr` has been a sucky way to manage subclassing for a long time.  Use `SetWindowSubclass` if you're going the WinApi route (but all C# UI frameworks so far have provided a class to make this easy, would be very surprised if the new one's any different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a blog article describing this exact task, and error message.

- [Accessing the WndProc in a UWP Application](https://www.travelneil.com/wndproc-in-uwp.html)

In that case the author was using `SetWindowLongPtr` to storing a pointer to the result of `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`, and calling it after C# has detected the delegate is unreachable.

You are keeping the delegate alive by storing it to a member variable.  `GCHandle.Alloc` would also have worked.  So that's fine... at least in the `Subclass` function.

However, your `Unsubclass` is broken.  You seem to have assumed that `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` is an inverse function for `GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`.  It's not, it creates a brand new trampoline linked to the managed delegate instance.  You need to preserve the original `oldDelegatePtr` and put it back.

In fact, you have no reason to use `GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` at all, since the old wndproc is only ever passed back to WinApi functions.  Just leave it as an `IntPtr`.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  I took onboard what you said, went through the article you mentioned, then simplified a few things down - like that hardcoding of the GUID for the COM interface was now totally unnecessary.

Comment: I added a second function as follows to keep the code simple:  ```[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtr")] // 64-bit
        public static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);```